# Find the cumulative average of the list [8,1,4,2,1] using accumulate() and lambda function in python

Tags: python-3.x, list, lambda, accumulate

Hi I am new to python I want to find the cummulative average of the given list using accumulate() and lambda function i have written code till accumulate() but I can't find the cummulative average using lambda function. Can anyone help me with it ?

```
enter code here
a= [8,1,4,2,6]
import itertools as it
l=[]
l = it.accumulate(a)
print(list(l))


My output should be like this [4.5,4.33,3.75,4.2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using accumulate is surely not the easiest/cleanest way to calculate a cumulative average. But you can do it for the fun. You'd have to apply it on `enumerate(a)` though since the lambda function has no idea of the position of its arguments in the list:

```
a= [8,1,4,2,6]
import itertools as it
l=[]
l = it.accumulate(list(enumerate(a)), lambda x,y: (y[0], (x[1]*(x[0]+1) + y[1])/(y[0]+1)))
print(list(map(lambda x: x[1], l)))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
from  itertools import accumulate
result=accumulate([8,1,4,2,6],lambda x,y:(x+y)/2)
for res in result :
    print(res)
```

Comment: 8
4.5
4.25
3.125
4.5625

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. ...instead of commenting.